# Como adicionar em um array Jquery itens de uma IENUMERABLE em .Net MVC?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

Como faço para adicionar itens de uma `IEnumerable<T>` em um array `JavaScript`?

View:

```
@using Colecao.ViewModels
@model ConfiguracoesViewModel

    @foreach (var equipamento in @Model.Equipamentos)
    { 
              //Gostaria de adicionar esses itens em um array JS.
    }
```

Comment: Em JavaScript não há `IEnumerable`...

Comment: Tá confuso de entender. Você quer passar um `IEnumerable` de uma Action para o seu JS? Ou o `IEnumerable` está no seu JS?

Comment: Eu passo o IEnumerable para a view! e no JS gostaria de manipular os itens da IEnumerable ,adicionando em um array .

Comment: @HansMiller como estás a passar para a view? podes colocar o código ou como aparece na view?

Comment: Entendi, tu tens algum código feito? Isso pode ajudar pra entender melhor o que você tem e o pessoal te ajudar da melhor maneira. Caso tenha, clica em [edit] e adiciona esses detalhes.

Answer (score 2):

Você pode fazer da seguinte forma:

```
var equipamentos = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.Equipamentos));
```

**Como utilizar?**

Você pode utilizar normalmente como se fosse um json qualquer.

Digamos que o meu model de equipamentos esteja assim:

```
public class Equipamentos
{
    public string Nome { get; set;}
    public string Modelo { get; set;}
}
```

A sua utilização será da seguinte forma:

```
alert("Nome: "+ equipamentos[1].Nome + " | Modelo: "+ equipamentos[1].Modelo);
```

Comment: Como posso manipular essa variavel dentro da minha funcao JS?

Comment: Como um array qualquer, só que as propriedades vão depender do seu model.

Comment: @HansMiller, vou editar a pergunta adicionando como utilizar

Comment: Blz! só uma duvida aonde eu ponho esta funcao?
 
var equipamentos=@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.Equipamentos));

Comment: @HansMiller, coloca dentro da sua tag `<script></script>`.

Comment: como ficaria  o foreach em JQUery para adicionar ao Array?

Comment: @HansMiller, mover o model pra um array ou mover `json` do model pra um array??

Comment: var equipamentos = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.Equipamentos));


como mover cada item que esta dentro da coleção equipamento para um array[].

Comment: @HansMiller, equipamentos já é um array. Um array de equipamento. Caso queira refazer a lista, pode fazer `$.each(dispositivos,function(key, value){ console.log(key + " | " + value.Nome + " - " + value.Numero );});`